# CDNify Not Getting Assets

Tags: cdn

I'm trying to add my website as a resource on [CDNify](http://cdnify.com), but it doesn't seem to be fetching my assets nor caching them.

[From their website:](https://cdnify.com/learn/getting-started)

> #### How long does it take the CDN to setup?
>
> 5-10 minutes, then your website will be mirrored by the CDN.

It's been well over an hour.

> #### Why aren't my assets being pulled?
>
> Check that your mirrored site is up and running, this is where your origin server will be grabbing your assets. If using a plugin, go to its settings to see that the option to pull your assets is selected. If updating your code manually, run through all the assets you want to update and then change them.

The website is definitely working, though.

Why else might my resources not be fetched by CDNify?

Comment: Are you sure that the origin server url is correct in the dashboard? Do you have any firewall that might be blocking the CDN servers from grabbing your content? What error are you receiving if you attempt to view your CDN url?

Comment: I know it's correct, some (4) assets are cached. When I try to visit the CDN url, I get redirected to my original url

Comment: Sounds like some sort of TTL/Propagation/Caching issue since parts of your assets are being cached. Regardless it sounds like a semi unique issue that I think you would be better off asking their support department about instead of ProWebmasters.

Comment: I did both. Partially to see how responsive this SE site is and if this is considered off topic.